# SOAP response object not populated using JAVA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, soap, apache-axis, soap-client

I want to read Multi reference elements from SOAP response mentioned below. I tried to read but multiRef elements I'm unable to parse ***responsecode*** element.
Please help me as I'm new for SOAP and some how I have to complete this task.

**SOAP XML response**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns1:doBillResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:ns1="urn:ms.model.response">
        <doBillReturn href="#id0"/>
    </ns1:doBillResponse>
    <multiRef id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:BillResponse"
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
        xmlns:ns2="http://model.ef.ms.resonse">
        <var1 xsi:type="soapenc:string">2</var1>
        <var2 xsi:type="soapenc:string">variabletwo</var2>
        <var3 xsi:type="soapenc:string">0025634838021</var3>

        <responseCode href="#id1"/>
    </multiRef>
    
    <multiRef id="id1" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:int"
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">6
    </multiRef>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Java Code for parsing:**

```
public static String ExtractResponse(String soapmessage,String var2, String var3) {

    CreateDirectory cd = new CreateDirectory();
    String result="";
    SOAPBody body =null;

    try {
        SOAPMessage respMsg = null;

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(soapmessage.getBytes());
        respMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
        body = respMsg.getSOAPBody();
        NodeList element1 = body.getElementsByTagName("var1");
        NodeList element2 = body.getElementsByTagName("var2");
        NodeList element3 = body.getElementsByTagName("var3");

        String TransactionNum = element1.item(0).getTextContent();
        String AcctResCode = element2.item(0).getTextContent();
        String ExpDate = element3.item(0).getTextContent();
        result = TransactionNum+"@"+AcctResCode+"@"+ExpDate;
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: does anyone know how to parse multiRef element **responseCode** ?